# Can 'なければなりません' be used for possibility?

Tags: grammar, modality, obligations

I thought the use of this suffix was restricted to obligations, but the sentence below has left me confused.

> この会に来たインドの人は「日本にいろいろ教えてもらって、早く空気をきれいにしなければなりません」と話していました。

Source: http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010874151000/k10010874151000.html

Comment: I don't understand why you are confused. So what do you think this sentence means?

Comment: An indian person that came to the meeting said: 'Japan taught us a lot of things. Possibly, our air will soon be beautiful'. Would it not be better instead of 'しなければなりません' write 'かもしれない', 'だろう' or 'でしょう'?

Comment: @Pagginelli Why do you think it would mean that?

Answer (score 4):

This しなければなりません just means "must", "need to", "have to". And that's the only meaning of しなければなりません.

> この会に来たインドの人は「日本にいろいろ教えてもらって、早く空気をきれいにしなければなりません」と話していました。
>
> - An Indian person who came to the meeting said, "[I] have to make the air (of India) clean after Japan taught a lot of things to [me]."
> - An Indian person who came to the meeting said, "[We Indian people] have to make the air (of India) clean after Japan taught a lot of things to [us]."

This person is probably someone in charge of the air pollution problem of India, but since the subject is omitted, the second interpretation is possible.

Comment: Since a group of officials and experts came to learn on behalf of their country, I would definitely go with the second interpretation. One person alone will probably have a very difficult time trying to clean up India's air.